# Reload a file in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

I edited a file in Sublime without saving it. Now I want to reload the saved version with discarding my changes. How is that possible? Do I really have to close the tab without saving and open it again manually or is there some hotkey to replace the shown version by the saved one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sublime 3: File -> Revert File

You can also bind a hotkey in Preferences -> Key Bindings - User

```
{
"keys": ["f10"],
"command": "revert"
}
```